# Is SwipeRefreshLayout compatible with an adapter that has multiple viewType?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am making a list, that will get more items when I go to the bottom of the list. I want this list to be refreshable too, so I need a `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Let's say I have an adapter like this :

```
class OrdersListAdapter(val selected : (Order) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    fun addOrders(orders: ArrayList<Order>) {
        this.orders.addAll(orders)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(this.orders.size - orders.size + FIRST_ITEM_INDEX, orders.size)
    }

    fun setFirstOrders(orders: ArrayList<Order>) {
        this.orders = orders
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return (orders.size + 1 + FIRST_ITEM_INDEX)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_ORDERS -> OrdersViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate<OrdersItemBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.orders_item, parent, false).apply {
                viewModel = OrdersViewModel()
            })
            else -> LoadingMoreOrdersViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate<LoadingMoreOrdersItemBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    R.layout.loading_more_orders_item, parent, false).apply {
                viewModel = LoadingMoreOrdersViewModel()
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            TYPE_ORDERS -> (holder as? OrdersViewHolder)?.setData(orders[position - FIRST_ITEM_INDEX])
            TYPE_LOADING -> (holder as? LoadingMoreOrdersViewHolder)?.setState(loading, error, noMoreItems)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
            if (position == FIRST_ITEM_INDEX - 1) TYPE_HEADER else if (position == itemCount - 1) TYPE_LOADING else TYPE_ORDERS
```

Well if I put my `RecyclerView` like this, inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/orders_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This will display all items, but the refreshLayout will not work : If I pull my view, nothing happens.

But if I do not set any loading layout inside my adapter (the one at bottom of the list, to load more items, inflated from `R.layout.loading_more_orders_item`), then the SwipeRefreshLayout will work properly.

How can I have 2 view types in my adapter, AND set my RecyclerView in a SwipeRefreshLayout ?

EDIT :

Here is my onRefreshListener :

```
refreshLayout = binding.swipeRefreshLayout

refreshLayout?.setOnRefreshListener { reloadOrders() }
```

And in reloadOrders() :

```
private fun reloadOrders() {
    viewModel.setLoading()
    refreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false
    Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe { getOrders() }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that wires your SwipeRefreshLayout with the adapter?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini In all my other views, I never bind my SwipeRefreshLayout with my RecyclerView, and it still works.

Comment: And where is your `onRefreshListener`? I've used this thing five or six times in the past 3-4 years. I've always used a listener (as described here): https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/respond-refresh-request (if there's another way to use it, I'm unaware, I'm asking out of curiosity)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I think I am doing as described in your man link, however the `onRefreshListener` is never call. When I swipe down no "bubble" with progress bar arrow is showing up on the top, as it should.
I have edit my question so you can see how I call the refresh.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the reloadOrders it doesn't get called? hmmm

Comment: Long shot guess: what happens if you change your recycler view's height to `match_parent` instead? I'm curious to see how the Swipe container behaves, but since you're pinning it to span the entire space to its parent, it wouldn't harm having the RV saving the height computation. (Also, your Swipe Layout width, should be 0dp because you're pinning it to the parent on start/end, so you should let the CL engine do its job) (In practice this may be harmless because I think CL 2.x ignores these, but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so thanks to @r2rek, I found a solution that worked for me :

In the code, we create a class that extends `LinearLayoutManager` and overrides method `canScrollVertically()` to always return false :

```
inner class MyLinearLayout(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return (false)
    }
}
```

Then, when we init our `RecyclerView`, we apply this class to our `layoutManager` :

```
ordersRv?.layoutManager = MyLinearLayout(this)
```

This will allow you to refresh, however you will not be able to scroll in your `RecyclerView` (duh).
To fix this, add a `NestedScrollView` in your xml, as following :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.ordersVisibility}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/orders_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

You can now scroll in your `RecyclerView`, and pull to refresh with your `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

I think this method is kinda hacky, so if someone have a better solution, feel free to tell us !

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what happens is the recyclerview takes over the ontouch events from swiperefreshlayout. You could try overwriting linearlayout and its `canScrollVertically()` method to return false. Cheers!

Comment: Your method worked, as I now can pull to refresh my `SwipeRefreshLayout`. However, I obviously can't scroll in my `RecyclerView` now. Any fix for this ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution !
I just added a `NestedScrollView` inside my `SwipeRefreshLayout`. In this `NestedScrollView`, I put my `RecyclerView`. It now works !

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, compatibility is not the issue you're having. Not sure of the size of your layout, as its height is 0dp. I'd play around with the view sizes and view hierarchy.

Comment: The size is 0dp because he is using ConstraintLayout (which can be inferred by the fact that he has constraints in the XML)